# Efficient Database interaction with a tracker/persister

Tags: php, mysql, database, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a class method named `->saveAll()`. This class tracks the objects that's to be put into the database. (Like what doctrine do)

What's the efficient way to save those objects? This is what I'm thinking right now (I'm going to be using MySQL as an example):

1. Open a connection to MySQL.
2. Perform a loop on all the objects.
3. Check which property has changed.
4. Perform a query with either `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.
5. When the loop finishes, closes the connection.

Is this the best way to do it? Or is there a better way to do it?

Also, let's say if i want to `->saveOne($object)`. Would the following be good:

1. Open connection
2. check for property changes
3. perform query
4. close connection

Comment: how about providing a custom _toString() function to return the data this object holding then simply you have to do nothing and automatically _toString() will called on each object and you can do what ever with the data

Comment: Do you mean the `__toString` will generate a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has a primary key or unique index, you can use a [REPLACE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) with all your data at once:

```
REPLACE INTO foo (id, bar) VALUES (NULL, 'baz'), (1, 'hello');
```

The row will be inserted if it does not exist or if the primary key/unique index is not specified. If the primary key or unique index is found, it will be updated instead.

Also, when MySQL executes an UPDATE (or when it updates through REPLACE), it will check each value to see if it has changed automatically (without the need to do it yourself) and leave it as-is if it hasn't, without any extra operation.

Comment: I'd say yes. You don't have to INSERT or UPDATE. You don't have to check if the properties have changed either (with an extra SELECT query) because MySQL will do it for you. You can do it all in a single query. You can also update multiple rows at once (unlike UPDATE).

Comment: Wait how do you update multiple rows at once with `REPLACE`? Is that a MySQL only feature or does other db also support it (I'm trying to support multiple db backends with a simple DB abstraction interface).

Comment: @ultimatebuster: REPLACE is an engine specific extension. MySQL has it. SQLite has it. Oracle has something called MERGE. MSSQL does not have it. PostgreSQL does not have it either. It's syntax is basically the same as INSERT (which supports multiple rows at once), but it will update the rows if they have a primary key/unique key and they already exists.